# Como fazer uma soma para cada grupo em uma coluna?

Tags: r, dplyr

Eu estou estudando R usando uma base de dados de covid e queria somar todos casos novos de acordo com a semana da epidemia. Por exemplo:

```
semanaEPI     CasosNovos 
1                 3
1                 2
1                 3
2                 4
2                 1
```

Eu queria que ele me devolvesse uma matriz assim

```
   SemanaEPI            SUM
      1                  8
      2                  5
```

EU tentei usar a função `group_by()` do pacote `dplyr`, mas não foi...

Answer (score 7):

Duas soluções.

### R base

A mais simples é com `aggregate`.

```r
aggregate(CasosNovos ~ semanaEPI, dados, sum)
#>   semanaEPI CasosNovos
#> 1         1          8
#> 2         2          5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

### Pacote `dplyr`

Duas soluções `dplyr`, uma contagem ponderada (*weighted* `count`) e com `group_by/summarise`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

dados %>% count(semanaEPI, wt = CasosNovos, name = "CasosNovos")
#>   semanaEPI CasosNovos
#> 1         1          8
#> 2         2          5

dados %>% 
  group_by(semanaEPI) %>%
  summarise(CasosNovos = sum(CasosNovos))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   semanaEPI CasosNovos
#>       <int>      <int>
#> 1         1          8
#> 2         2          5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

### Dados

```r
x<-'semanaEPI     CasosNovos 
1                 3
1                 2
1                 3
2                 4
2                 1'
dados <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>